# What does "Unable to inject Capacitor" mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: capacitor

I tried migrating a Cordova test app to Capacitor according to [1](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor/) and encountered the following error in logcat on Android:

```
E/Capacitor( 3537): Unable to inject Capacitor, Plugins won't work
```

and the `deviceready` event seems to be missing.

Here is `www/index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>demo-app</h1>
    <div id="status"/>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is `www/app.js`:

```js
document
  .getElementById('status')
  .appendChild(document.createElement('b'))
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode('status:'))

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  document
    .getElementById('status')
    .appendChild(document.createElement('i'))
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode('ready'))
})
```

FYI the Cordova test app was generated by [`generate-cordova-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-cordova-package) and modified to remove the extremely simple HEADER and CSS.

[1] https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor/

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of research, I discovered the following gem from [this comment on ionic-team/capacitor issue 1572](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1572#issuecomment-495726425):

> Capacitor injects itself into html files searching for the head tag

So just inserting `<head></head>` into the HTML resolves this issue and causes the Cordova-compatible `deviceready` event to be sent.

I really hope to see this documented in [1](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor/) and [2](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/) the near future.

[1] https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor/

[2] https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/

P.S. This subject is also discussed here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-inject-capacitor/178713

I raised this PR to get this documented: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/3024